# ASP.Net C# Master Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a question about the ****.Master Site a in ASP.NET with C# (WebForms).
I've created a Site.Masters File with a lot of differente Placeholders inside. So the question is - is it possible to fill the Placeholders from different .aspx Files?

**.Master** Page:

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainHeader" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainFooter" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Now i would do something like this:

1. Adding some Content to the Main Header  - the Content is represented in a file called mainHeader.aspx
2. Adding some Content to the Main Content - the Content is represented in a file calle mainContent.apsx

Is this possible or is there a solution for my plan? I would like to create a modular and flat structure of my .NET Project.

Thanks for your help - best regards

Comment: When you say "modify from different .aspx files", you mean modification from code behid (.aspx.cs ) at some stage of page life-cycle?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy I have different .aspx Files and i would like to Show all of this different .aspx Files in one Site. So there is the Container ***.Master which should fit all of the different .aspx Files and of course each of this .aspx Files have code behind

Comment: Still not clear what you want to achieve. Let's say you have text input. After user inputed 1 as input, you load page1.aspx, and if user input 2 as input you want to load page2.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want by using jquery.load(), here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/load/, however i think what you are doing is not the way to procede, in order to do what you want i suggest yo to do this:

Create User Controls, one for each master ContentPlaceHolder, then in your master, add each one of this and initiate them.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not how Master Pages work.

When the user/client requests an individual content Page, that Page is merged with the Master Page. The Master Page can not be called by the user/client.

I believe [User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) are what you are looking for.